# Using interface without declaring it in the class declaration

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I implemented 2 classes:

```
public class A
{
   public string GetName()
   {
       return "Class A";
   }
}

public class B
{
    public string GetName()
    {
        return "Class B";
    }
}
```

I also created an interface that is not been assign to class A and B:

```
public interface TellMyNameInterface
{
    string GetName();
}
```

I want to use the interface with class A and B:

```
TellMyNameInterface a = new A();  
TellMyNameInterface b = new B();
string aName= a.GetName();
```

Is there any way to use an instance of class A or B with that interface without declaring it in the class declaration?

Comment: No. You might want to implement a class adapter.

Comment: No, why would you want to follow a contract without admitting that you are?

Comment: you could use an extension method. you could then use the syntax a.GetName(). But with an extension method you cannot access instance state(properties values ect...)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, but you can write adapter classes to make it more convenient to do the conversions, and then use extension methods to make creating the adapter classes look more natural (and in fact hide the adapter classes behind the interface).

You would normally only do this if you are unable to change the original class definitions to implement the required interface directly.

So given these classes that you cannot edit:

```
public class A
{
    public string GetName()
    {
        return "Class A";
    }
}

public class B
{
    public string GetName()
    {
        return "Class B";
    }
}
```

And this interface that you really want them to implement, but can't:

```
public interface ITellMyNameInterface
{
    string GetName();
}
```

You can write a couple of adapter classes that *do* implement the interface, like this:

```
public class AAdapter: ITellMyNameInterface
{
    public AAdapter(A a)
    {
        _a = a;
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return _a.GetName();
    }

    private readonly A _a;
}

public class BAdapter: ITellMyNameInterface
{
    public BAdapter(B b)
    {
        _b = b;
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return _b.GetName();
    }

    private readonly B _b;
}
```

Then write extension methods to make it more natural to create the adapter classes:

```
public static class ABExt
{
    public static ITellMyNameInterface AsITellMyNameInterface(this A self)
    {
        return new AAdapter(self);
    }

    public static ITellMyNameInterface AsITellMyNameInterface(this B self)
    {
        return new BAdapter(self);
    }
}
```

Once you've done all that, it does at least make it simpler to get the `ITellMyNameInterface` for an instance of `A` or `B`, like so:

```
ITellMyNameInterface a = new A().AsITellMyNameInterface();
ITellMyNameInterface b = new B().AsITellMyNameInterface();
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can not. The only way i can see is using `object` to store it and then call the functions via reflection.